# How to setup and run python-lambda-local in Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, aws-lambda

I am new to python-lambda-local and Mac OS.
I am trying to run and test a simple python-lambda-local handler from VSCode editor in Mac OS locally.

I installed python-lambda-local using "pip3 install python-lambda-local" and it installed the package successfully.
I am able to see this in the list of libraries installed using "pip3 freeze".

But when I am trying to run the below command:

```
python-lambda-local -l lib/ -f handler -t 5 test.py event.json
```

I am getting below error:

```
bash: python-lambda-local: command not found
```

Is there any setting I have to do or how can I run this in my VSCode editor or in terminal.

FYR:

test.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from rx import Observable


def handler(event, context):
    xs = Observable.from_(range(event['answer']))
    ys = xs.to_blocking()
    zs = (x*x for x in ys if x % 7 == 0)
    for x in zs:
        print(x)
```

event.json:

> {
> "answer": 42
> }

Comment: you have installed python-lambda-local as a pip package not as executable you may be able to invoke it using python -m